# Protractor `addMockModule()` with arguments not handling structured data properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, protractor

I recently read about the solution for these protractor issues:

- [Unable to easily pass context to `addMockModule` #695](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/695)
- [feat(addMockModule): add third parameter to pass context #787](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/787)

I have been eager to DRY up my protractor tests and this was the solution I needed. This solution is working great with ChromeDriver, but with FirefoxDriver it's oddly broken. Here's my code (in a `beforeEach()` block:

```
  var httpBackendMock = function() {
      angular.module('httpBackendMock', ['ngMockE2E'])
        .value('mockData', arguments[0])
        .run(function ($httpBackend, mockData) {
          $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*aggregates/)
            .respond(200, mockData.testAggregates);
          $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*merchants\/123456/)
            .respond(200, mockData.testMerchant);
        });
  };
  browser.addMockModule('httpBackendMock', httpBackendMock, {
    testAggregates: testAggregates,
    testMerchant: testMerchant
  });
```

(`testAggregates` and `testMerchant` are defined previously.)

This works perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox when the `whenGET` expectations fire they return no data. It fails whether I use the `mockData` object or directly use `arguments[0]`.

But it gets weirder. If I try to inspect the `mockData` module value I created above in a later `browser.executeScript()` call, the data is there, and `console.log` renders it the same way in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
  browser.get('index.html#/experiments');
  browser.executeScript(function() {
    return angular.injector(["httpBackendMock"]).get('mockData');
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log("DATA", data);
  });
```

When the test runs the data shows up as expected.

The only workaround for this I have found is to `JSON.stringify()` the input to `addMockModule()` and `JSON.parse()` it inside. It seems to work, but is ugly - the framework should already be taking care of it.

So I think this is a bug, but I'm really not sure *which* component this is a bug *in*.

Comment: Thanks for the *stringify* hint, works for me too. Seems to be a lot of issues between selenium and recent versions of Firefox lately.

Comment: That's definitely true. Currently Firefox 35 doesn't work, though the fix is in. See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390

Comment: This has been fixed in Protractor 1.8 (Or rather, it's been fixed in Selenium 2.45, and Protractor 1.8 has updated to that.)

Comment: do you know if this work around could work with functions?

Comment: Highly unlikely @germanio